# How to open Google Play from the phone remotely on the watch (Wear OS)

Tags: android, wear-os

What is the correct way to remotely open Google Play from the phone on the watch (Wear OS)? I am trying this:

```
Intent intentOnWatch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
        .setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=\" + getPackageName()"));

RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(getApplicationContext(), intentOnWatch, null, null);
```

But nothing happens.

The last parameter is the nodeId. I left it as zero because the documentation says :

**nodeId**  *String: Wear OS node id for the device where the activity should be started. If null, and the current device is a watch, the activity will start on the companion phone device. Otherwise, the activity will start on all connected watch devices.*

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/wearable/intent/RemoteIntent#startremoteactivity

I could determine the nodeId, but it seems difficult to do. Plus in this case, starting the activity on all connected watch devices would be fine.

Is it possible to download a file using DownloadManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example (sorry it's Kotlin) should work

```
            val remoteActivityHelper =
                RemoteActivityHelper(application, Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())

            val nodes = Wearable.getNodeClient(application).connectedNodes.await()
            val nodeId = nodes.firstOrNull { it.displayName == "XXX" }?.id

            if (nodeId == null) {
                Toast.makeText(application, "No connected wear watch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                try {
                    remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                            .setData(
                                Uri.parse("https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/${programme.code}")
                            ),
                    ).await()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    toaster.showToast("Unable to open mobile app: ${e.message}")
                }
            }
        }
```

But the main thing in your example is that you are not checking the result of startRemoteActivity, it returns a ListenableFuture, so you could check for an error. In the example above, I'm using the .await() extension function which does the same thing.

There are more complete examples in https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/d18c489ff415aa0fbb25c260e3aacdf50f7716e3/WearVerifyRemoteApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/wearverifyremoteapp/MainMobileActivity.kt

I'm not sure about the exact implementation for Java, it's really messy with the Task and Future APIs mixed here. Maybe

```
        RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(application, executor);

        NodeClient client = Wearable.getNodeClient(application);
        client.getConnectedNodes().addOnSuccessListener(nodes -> {
                if (nodes.size() > 0) {
                    String nodeId = nodes.get(0).getId();
                    ListenableFuture<Void> result = remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                                    .setData(
                                            Uri.parse("https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/${programme.code}")
                                    )
                            , nodeId);
                    result.addListener(() -> {
                        try {
                            result.get();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(application, "Failed " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, executor);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(application, "No connected wear watch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }).addOnFailureListener(failure -> {
            Toast.makeText(application, "Unable to open mobile app: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri! Unfortunately, I really don't have any experience with Kotlin. Is there a way to convert this code to Java?

Comment: Added something, but it's not very simple or clean. You may need to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting with exatly the same problem last two days.
Works for me the next code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
        .setData(Uri.parse(PLAY_STORE_APP_URI));

    for (Node node : nodesWithoutApp) {
        RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = 
            new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(intent, node.getId());
    }
```

It didn't work with RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity for some reason.

Comment: Thank you Oleg! I tried to implement this, but how do I determine nodesWithoutApp? Also, I get "Cannot resolve symbol RemoteActivityHelper". I found an example in the internet (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/developers/samples/android/+/3cdb494%5E%21/) but it looks very complicated to me, with lots of code. Moreover, there are some 'deprecated' functions there (like CapabilityApi). What can I do?

Comment: I used this example: https://github.com/jimmyFlash/wear2test/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/jamalsafwat/wear2test/MainActivity.java
Add implementation 'androidx.wear:wear-remote-interactions:1.0.0' to your mobile build.gradle to use RemoteActivityHelper.
Target Node Id can be null. Look here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/remote/interactions/RemoteActivityHelper

Comment: Thanks Oleg! Finally, I could make it work. This would be the simpler solution, without having to take care of the nodes.

Comment: Is it possible to download a file using DownloadManager?